# dataframe representation of a rolling window

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I want a dataframe representation of of a rolling window.  Instead of performing some operation on a rolling window, I want a dataframe where the window is represented in another dimension.  This could be as a `pd.Panel` or `np.array` or a `pd.DataFrame` with a `pd.MultiIndex`.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3).round(2), 
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                  index=list('abcdefghij'))

print df

      A     B     C
a  0.44  0.41  0.46
b  0.47  0.46  0.02
c  0.85  0.82  0.78
d  0.76  0.93  0.83
e  0.88  0.93  0.72
f  0.12  0.15  0.20
g  0.44  0.10  0.28
h  0.61  0.09  0.84
i  0.74  0.87  0.69
j  0.38  0.23  0.44
```

#### Expected Output

For a `window = 2` I'd expect the result to be.

```
      0                 1            
      A     B     C     A     B     C
a  0.44  0.41  0.46  0.47  0.46  0.02
b  0.47  0.46  0.02  0.85  0.82  0.78
c  0.85  0.82  0.78  0.76  0.93  0.83
d  0.76  0.93  0.83  0.88  0.93  0.72
e  0.88  0.93  0.72  0.12  0.15  0.20
f  0.12  0.15  0.20  0.44  0.10  0.28
g  0.44  0.10  0.28  0.61  0.09  0.84
h  0.61  0.09  0.84  0.74  0.87  0.69
i  0.74  0.87  0.69  0.38  0.23  0.44
```

I'm not determined to have the layout presented this way, but this is the information I want.  I'm looking for the most efficient way to get at this.

#### What I've done so far

I've experimented with using `shift` in varying ways but it feels clunky.  This is what I use to produce the output above:

```
print pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1)], axis=1, keys=[0, 1]).dropna()
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this? That's the important question, whatever it is, you can probably do this without an intermediary DataFrame (like the expected one).

Comment: @AndyHayden I want to calculate coskew and cokurtosis.  I expect to demean across this new dimension and perform the appropriated matrix multiplications to get the job done.  For the case of correlation and covariance, it's easy.  `df.rolling(2).corr()`.  But I have to use `df.rolling(2).apply` for something more complicated.  Plus, I'm experimenting with various methods of vectorizing.  Also, I'm running a few calculations that require the same intermediate information.  I'd like to calculate and store it possibly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We could use NumPy to get views into those sliding windows with its *esoteric* [`strided tricks`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides). If you are using this new dimension for some reduction like matrix-multiplication, this would be ideal. If for some reason, you want to have a `2D` output, we need to use a reshape at the end, which will result in creating a copy though.

Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided

def get_sliding_window(df, W, return2D=0):
    a = df.values                 
    s0,s1 = a.strides
    m,n = a.shape
    out = strided(a,shape=(m-W+1,W,n),strides=(s0,s0,s1))
    if return2D==1:
        return out.reshape(a.shape[0]-W+1,-1)
    else:
        return out
```

Sample run for 2D/3D output -

```
In [68]: df
Out[68]: 
      A     B
0  0.44  0.41
1  0.46  0.47
2  0.46  0.02
3  0.85  0.82
4  0.78  0.76

In [70]: get_sliding_window(df, 3,return2D=1)
Out[70]: 
array([[ 0.44,  0.41,  0.46,  0.47,  0.46,  0.02],
       [ 0.46,  0.47,  0.46,  0.02,  0.85,  0.82],
       [ 0.46,  0.02,  0.85,  0.82,  0.78,  0.76]])
```

Here's how the 3D views output would look like -

```
In [69]: get_sliding_window(df, 3,return2D=0)
Out[69]: 
array([[[ 0.44,  0.41],
        [ 0.46,  0.47],
        [ 0.46,  0.02]],

       [[ 0.46,  0.47],
        [ 0.46,  0.02],
        [ 0.85,  0.82]],

       [[ 0.46,  0.02],
        [ 0.85,  0.82],
        [ 0.78,  0.76]]])
```

Let's time it for views `3D` output for various window sizes -

```
In [331]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 3).round(2))

In [332]: %timeit get_3d_shfted_array(df,2) # @Yakym Pirozhenko's soln
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.9 µs per loop

In [333]: %timeit get_sliding_window(df,2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.2 µs per loop

In [334]: %timeit get_3d_shfted_array(df,5) # @Yakym Pirozhenko's soln
10000 loops, best of 3: 89.9 µs per loop

In [335]: %timeit get_sliding_window(df,5)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.4 µs per loop

In [336]: %timeit get_3d_shfted_array(df,15) # @Yakym Pirozhenko's soln
1000 loops, best of 3: 258 µs per loop

In [337]: %timeit get_sliding_window(df,15)
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.8 µs per loop
```

Let's verify that we are indeed getting views -

```
In [338]: np.may_share_memory(get_sliding_window(df,2), df.values)
Out[338]: True
```

The almost constant timings with `get_sliding_window` even across various window sizes suggest the huge benefit of getting the view instead of copying.

Comment: You're getting a lot of milage answering my old questions.  :-)  Glad you are!

Comment: @piRSquared Just leveraging on your easy questions :)

Comment: I do try to tee them up nicely.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks to you both. Can't wait for this to be built into pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimers:

First, I would not call the method you provide clunky. It is readable and you can easily generalize with a list comprehension to any window size. At the same time, this is somewhat of an open ended question that may have many solutions, including your own.

/Disclaimers

Here is one other method that I think qualifies under your description:

Use `np.dstack` on `df.values`. One benefit over existing approach is construction speed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''
      A     B     C
a  0.44  0.41  0.46
b  0.47  0.46  0.02
c  0.85  0.82  0.78
d  0.76  0.93  0.83
e  0.88  0.93  0.72
f  0.12  0.15  0.20
g  0.44  0.10  0.28
h  0.61  0.09  0.84
i  0.74  0.87  0.69
j  0.38  0.23  0.44
'''), sep=r' +')


window = 2

def get_3d_shfted_array(df, window=window):
    rows = df.values
    res  = np.dstack((rows[i:i-window] for i in range(window)))
    return res
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 15.5 µs per loop

res  = get_3d_shfted_array(df)
zero = res[...,0]
one  = res[...,1]


# current method
def get_multiindexed_array(df, window=window):
    return pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1)], axis=1, keys=[0, 1]).dropna()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 928 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  You've taught about `np.dstack` and this is very quick.

Comment: Glad I could help.