# why does pandas rolling use single dimension ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, pandas-groupby

I was motivated to use pandas `rolling` feature to perform a rolling multi-factor regression (This question is **NOT** about rolling multi-factor regression).  I expected that I'd be able to use `apply` after a `df.rolling(2)` and take the resulting `pd.DataFrame` extract the ndarray with `.values` and perform the requisite matrix multiplication.  It didn't work out that way.

Here is what I found:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2).round(2), columns=['A', 'B'])
X = np.random.rand(2, 1).round(2)
```

What do objects look like:

```
print "\ndf = \n", df
print "\nX = \n", X
print "\ndf.shape =", df.shape, ", X.shape =", X.shape

df = 
      A     B
0  0.44  0.41
1  0.46  0.47
2  0.46  0.02
3  0.85  0.82
4  0.78  0.76

X = 
[[ 0.93]
 [ 0.83]]

df.shape = (5, 2) , X.shape = (2L, 1L)
```

Matrix multiplication behaves normally:

```
df.values.dot(X)

array([[ 0.7495],
       [ 0.8179],
       [ 0.4444],
       [ 1.4711],
       [ 1.3562]])
```

Using apply to perform row by row dot product behaves as expected:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.values.dot(X)[0], axis=1)

0    0.7495
1    0.8179
2    0.4444
3    1.4711
4    1.3562
dtype: float64
```

Groupby -> Apply behaves as I'd expect:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.values.dot(X)[0, 0])

0    0.7495
1    0.8179
2    0.4444
3    1.4711
4    1.3562
dtype: float64
```

But when I run:

```
df.rolling(1).apply(lambda x: x.values.dot(X))
```

I get:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Ok, so pandas is using straight `ndarray` within its `rolling` implementation.  I can handle that.  Instead of using `.values` to get the `ndarray`, let's try:

```
df.rolling(1).apply(lambda x: x.dot(X))
```

> shapes (1,) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 0) != 2 (dim 0)

Wait!  What?!

So I created a custom function to look at the what rolling is doing.

```
def print_type_sum(x):
    print type(x), x.shape
    return x.sum()
```

Then ran:

```
print df.rolling(1).apply(print_type_sum)

<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (1L,)
      A     B
0  0.44  0.41
1  0.46  0.47
2  0.46  0.02
3  0.85  0.82
4  0.78  0.76
```

My resulting `pd.DataFrame` is the same, that's good.  But it printed out 10 single dimensional `ndarray` objects.  What about `rolling(2)`

```
print df.rolling(2).apply(print_type_sum)

<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (2L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (2L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (2L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (2L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (2L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (2L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (2L,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (2L,)
      A     B
0   NaN   NaN
1  0.90  0.88
2  0.92  0.49
3  1.31  0.84
4  1.63  1.58
```

Same thing, expect output but it printed 8 `ndarray` objects.  `rolling` is producing a single dimensional `ndarray` of length `window` for each column as opposed to what I expected which was an `ndarray` of shape `(window, len(df.columns))`.

## Question is Why?

I now don't have a way to easily run a rolling multi-factor regression.

Comment: This is a [known issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21026837/5276797). I recently asked Jeff about it, you can read his answer in the comments!

Comment: What is the state-of-art solution as of Pandas 0.20? Seems like lots of improvements have been made. Is the objective in OP achievable using rolling().apply() directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [`strides views concept on dataframe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41406783/3293881), here's a vectorized approach -

```
get_sliding_window(df, 2).dot(X) # window size = 2
```

Runtime test -

```
In [101]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2).round(2), columns=['A', 'B'])

In [102]: X = np.array([2, 3])

In [103]: rolled_df = roll(df, 2)

In [104]: %timeit rolled_df.apply(lambda df: pd.Series(df.values.dot(X)))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.51 ms per loop

In [105]: %timeit get_sliding_window(df, 2).dot(X)
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.7 µs per loop
```

Verify results -

```
In [106]: rolled_df.apply(lambda df: pd.Series(df.values.dot(X)))
Out[106]: 
      0     1
1  2.70  4.09
2  4.09  2.52
3  2.52  1.78
4  1.78  3.50

In [107]: get_sliding_window(df, 2).dot(X)
Out[107]: 
array([[ 2.7 ,  4.09],
       [ 4.09,  2.52],
       [ 2.52,  1.78],
       [ 1.78,  3.5 ]])
```

Huge improvement there, which I am hoping would stay noticeable on larger arrays!

Comment: i get an unsolved reference error when trying to use get_sliding_window

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to share what I've done to work around this problem.

Given a `pd.DataFrame` and a window, I generate a stacked `ndarray` using `np.dstack` ([**see answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37448165/2336654)).  I then convert it to a `pd.Panel` and using `pd.Panel.to_frame` convert it to a `pd.DataFrame`.  At this point, I have a `pd.DataFrame` that has an additional level on its index relative to the original `pd.DataFrame` and the new level contains information about each rolled period.  For example, if the roll window is 3, the new index level will contain be `[0, 1, 2]`.  An item for each period.  I can now `groupby` `level=0` and return the groupby object.  This now gives me an object that I can much more intuitively manipulate.

## Roll Function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def roll(df, w):
    roll_array = np.dstack([df.values[i:i+w, :] for i in range(len(df.index) - w + 1)]).T
    panel = pd.Panel(roll_array, 
                     items=df.index[w-1:],
                     major_axis=df.columns,
                     minor_axis=pd.Index(range(w), name='roll'))
    return panel.to_frame().unstack().T.groupby(level=0)
```

## Demonstration

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2).round(2), columns=['A', 'B'])

print df

      A     B
0  0.44  0.41
1  0.46  0.47
2  0.46  0.02
3  0.85  0.82
4  0.78  0.76
```

Let's `sum`

```
rolled_df = roll(df, 2)

print rolled_df.sum()

major     A     B
1      0.90  0.88
2      0.92  0.49
3      1.31  0.84
4      1.63  1.58
```

To peek under the hood, we can see the stucture:

```
print rolled_df.apply(lambda x: x)

major      A     B
  roll            
1 0     0.44  0.41
  1     0.46  0.47
2 0     0.46  0.47
  1     0.46  0.02
3 0     0.46  0.02
  1     0.85  0.82
4 0     0.85  0.82
  1     0.78  0.76
```

But what about the purpose for which I built this, rolling multi-factor regression.  But I'll settle for matrix multiplication for now.

```
X = np.array([2, 3])

print rolled_df.apply(lambda df: pd.Series(df.values.dot(X))) 

      0     1
1  2.11  2.33
2  2.33  0.98
3  0.98  4.16
4  4.16  3.84
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks.  I ran into a little trouble with nan values, but updating the last line of the `roll` function to use `.to_frame(filter_observations=False)` fixed my issue.

Comment: This is helpful. But is there way to make the 'roll' column keep the original index? e.g.  0.46  0.47 is always associated with "1". Thank you.

Comment: This is cool, but why the heck isn't this a feature of Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Made the following modifications to the above answer since I needed to return the entire rolling window as is done in pd.DataFrame.rolling()

```
def roll(df, w):
    roll_array = np.dstack([df.values[i:i+w, :] for i in range(len(df.index) - w + 1)]).T
    roll_array_full_window = np.vstack((np.empty((w-1 ,len(df.columns), w)), roll_array))
    panel = pd.Panel(roll_array_full_window, 
                 items=df.index,
                 major_axis=df.columns,
                 minor_axis=pd.Index(range(w), name='roll'))
    return panel.to_frame().unstack().T.groupby(level=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Since pandas v0.23 it is now possible to pass a `Series` instead of a `ndarray` to Rolling.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/whatsnew.html#rolling-expanding-apply-accepts-raw-false-to-pass-a-series-to-the-function). Just set `raw=False`.

> **raw** : bool, default None
>
> `False` : passes each row or column as a Series to the function.
>
> `True` or `None` : the passed function will receive ndarray objects instead. If you are just applying a NumPy reduction function this will achieve much better performance.
>   The raw parameter is required and will show a FutureWarning if not passed. In the future raw will default to False.
>
> *New in version 0.23.0.*

As noted; if you only need one single dimension, passing it raw is obviously more efficient. This is probably the answer to your question; Rolling.apply() was initially built to pass an `ndarray` only because this is the most efficient.