# How to invoke pandas.rolling.apply with parameters from multiple column?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataset:

```
    Open     High      Low    Close        
0  132.960  133.340  132.940  133.105
1  133.110  133.255  132.710  132.755
2  132.755  132.985  132.640  132.735 
3  132.730  132.790  132.575  132.685
4  132.685  132.785  132.625  132.755
```

I try to use rolling.apply function for all rows, like this:

```
df['new_col']= df[['Open']].rolling(2).apply(AccumulativeSwingIndex(df['High'],df['Low'],df['Close']))
```

- shows error

or

```
df['new_col']=  df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']].rolling(2).apply(AccumulativeSwingIndex)
```

- pass only parameter from column 'Open'

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't know where `AccumulativeSwingIndex` comes from.  See if my answer is helpful.

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this question?

Answer (score 27):

#### Define your own `roll`

We can create a function that takes a window size argument `w` and any other keyword arguments.  We use this to build a new `DataFrame` in which we will call `groupby` on while passing on the keyword arguments via `kwargs`.

Note: I didn't have to use `stride_tricks.as_strided` but it is succinct and in my opinion appropriate.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as stride
import pandas as pd

def roll(df, w, **kwargs):
    v = df.values
    d0, d1 = v.shape
    s0, s1 = v.strides

    a = stride(v, (d0 - (w - 1), w, d1), (s0, s0, s1))

    rolled_df = pd.concat({
        row: pd.DataFrame(values, columns=df.columns)
        for row, values in zip(df.index, a)
    })

    return rolled_df.groupby(level=0, **kwargs)

roll(df, 2).mean()

       Open      High       Low    Close
0  133.0350  133.2975  132.8250  132.930
1  132.9325  133.1200  132.6750  132.745
2  132.7425  132.8875  132.6075  132.710
3  132.7075  132.7875  132.6000  132.720
```

We can also use the `pandas.DataFrame.pipe` method to the same effect:

```
df.pipe(roll, w=2).mean()
```

---

---

#### OLD ANSWER

**`Panel` has been deprecated.  See above for updated answer.**

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37491779/2336654

define our own `roll`

```
def roll(df, w, **kwargs):
    roll_array = np.dstack([df.values[i:i+w, :] for i in range(len(df.index) - w + 1)]).T
    panel = pd.Panel(roll_array, 
                     items=df.index[w-1:],
                     major_axis=df.columns,
                     minor_axis=pd.Index(range(w), name='roll'))
    return panel.to_frame().unstack().T.groupby(level=0, **kwargs)
```

you should be able to:

```
roll(df, 2).apply(your_function)
```

Using `mean`

```
roll(df, 2).mean()

major      Open      High       Low    Close
1      133.0350  133.2975  132.8250  132.930
2      132.9325  133.1200  132.6750  132.745
3      132.7425  132.8875  132.6075  132.710
4      132.7075  132.7875  132.6000  132.720
```

---

```
f = lambda df: df.sum(1)

roll(df, 2, group_keys=False).apply(f)

   roll
1  0       532.345
   1       531.830
2  0       531.830
   1       531.115
3  0       531.115
   1       530.780
4  0       530.780
   1       530.850
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I got MemoryError with this.

Comment: @AndyHayden Updated.

Comment: @piRSquared thanks! It's a little surprising there isn't a vanilla pandas way to do this. Feels quite a natural thing to want to do.

Comment: It's a very useful function, which I was missing in the Pandas API. How would you approach the same task if you would want to use a window as a datetime frequency (for example `win="3D"`)?

Comment: @MaxU that’s a good question. I’ll give it some thought when I have a chance.

Comment: @piRSquared Any more thoughts on running this window method with a datetime offset?

Comment: @blalterman no unfortunately.  I haven't had the time to do most of what I want to do (-:

Comment: Nice approach, but it's very slow compared to basic DataFrame.rolling(period).apply. This really should be a part of the standard optimized pandas API...

Comment: @SebastianJylanki The slow part comes from the `pd.concat` operation, and it can be bypassed.

Answer (score 4):

As your rolling window is not too large, I think you can also put them in the same dataframe then use the `apply` function to reduce.

For example, with the dataset `df` as following

```
            Open    High        Low     Close
Date                
2017-11-07  258.97  259.3500    258.09  258.67
2017-11-08  258.47  259.2200    258.15  259.11
2017-11-09  257.73  258.3900    256.36  258.17
2017-11-10  257.73  258.2926    257.37  258.09
2017-11-13  257.31  258.5900    257.27  258.33
```

You can just add the rolling data to this dataframe with

```
window = 2
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
for i in range(window):
    df_shifted = df.shift(i).copy()
    df_shifted.columns = ["{}-{}".format(s, i) for s in df.columns]
    df1 = df1.join(df_shifted)
df1

           Open-0   High-0      Low-0   Close-0 Open-1  High-1      Low-1   Close-1
Date                                
2017-11-07  258.97  259.3500    258.09  258.67  NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN
2017-11-08  258.47  259.2200    258.15  259.11  258.97  259.3500    258.09  258.67
2017-11-09  257.73  258.3900    256.36  258.17  258.47  259.2200    258.15  259.11
2017-11-10  257.73  258.2926    257.37  258.09  257.73  258.3900    256.36  258.17
2017-11-13  257.31  258.5900    257.27  258.33  257.73  258.2926    257.37  258.09
```

Then you can make an apply on it easily with all the rolling data you want with

```
df1.apply(AccumulativeSwingIndex, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a workaround I came up with:

```py
df['new_col'] = list(map(fn, df.rolling(2)))
```

Comment: May I ask what is fn?

Comment: It's any function that will take the rolling window as a parameter and compute the transformation you want.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered some problems alike. the following lines may help you out.
this might be the simplest solution for retrieving the data(matrices) within dataframe.rolling(), after which we can do almost anything with it. As comparison, d.rolling().apply() only allows aggregation functions.

```py
size = 20
matrices = [x.values for x in d.rolling(size)][size-1:]
len(matrices)
[do_anything(i) for i in matrices]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
ggg = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "b":[7,6,5,4,3,2,1]})

def my_rolling_apply2(df, fun, window, if_prepend=True):
    prepend = [None] * (window - 1)
    end = len(df) - window
    mid = map(lambda start: fun(df[start:start + window]), np.arange(0,end))
    last =  fun(df[end:])
    if if_prepend:
        return [*prepend, *mid, last]
    else:
        return [*mid, last, *prepend]

display(my_rolling_apply2(ggg, lambda df: (df["a"].max(), df["b"].min()), 3))
display(my_rolling_apply2(ggg, lambda df: (df["a"].max(), df["b"].min()), 3, False))
```

And the result:

```
[None, None, (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 1)]
[(3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 1), None, None]
```

Answer (score -4):

If you're trying to apply the function to all rows of all columns:

```
df.rolling(size_of_your_window).apply(your_function_here)
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this for passing multiple columns to apply

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: your_function(x['High'],x['Low'],x['Close']), axis=1)
```

Comment: how do we pass the window size?

Comment: this does not address how to pass a window size, which is what the question asked