# Access all columns in a pandas rolling call

Tags: python, pandas

I'm interested in computing a statistic over a rolling window. The statistic will be computed over multiple columns.  Here is a toy example calculating regression coefficients over a rolling window.

```
def regression_coef(df):
    if df.shape[0]==0:
        return np.array([np.NaN, np.NaN])
    y = df.y.values
    X = df.drop('y',axis = 1).values
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(X,y).coef_.round(2)
    return reg

time = np.arange(5,3605,5)
x = np.random.normal(size = time.size)
z = np.random.normal(size = time.size)
y = 2*x+z + np.random.normal(size = time.size) 
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'z':z, 'y':y}, index = pd.to_datetime(time, unit ='s'))
```

When I call `df.rolling('20 T').apply(regression_coef)` I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'y'`.  This leads me to believe that `df.rolling` is computes statistics over the individual columns, rather than finding all observations within the 20 minute window.

How can I achieve what I want?  That is to say, how can I compute `regression_coef` in a rolling window?  In particular, I'm interested if this can be solved for use with offsets and with the existing pandas API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke pandas.rolling.apply with parameters from multiple column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878917/how-to-invoke-pandas-rolling-apply-with-parameters-from-multiple-column)

Comment: @tvgriek this problem uses offsets rather than number of observations.  I think it is distinct from the question you linked.

Comment: have you tried the custom roll function defined in there? I have checked the rolling behavior, it stacks all the columns and goes over all values. total length: 3x 720. You could implement a custom function that processes a stacked column.

Comment: @tvgriek I've tried the function in that answer.  It doesn't work with offsets.  I'm capable of writing my own function to solve this, but I'd like to know if it is possible with the existing pandas API.

Comment: @Demetri Pananos Have you find a solution for this?  I have a similar question that requires all columns of `df` to be passed to the function.  Hoping for Pandas API based solution.  see:[link]  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345510/rolling-apply-on-custom-function-that-requires-multiple-columns-of-dataframe-to?noredirect=1#comment101184613_57345510)

Comment: @Balki No I haven't found a satisfactory answer.