# rolling.apply on custom function that requires multiple columns of dataframe to reduce single column

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to create an additional column of my `df['newc']` through rolling.apply on `df['cond']` with a custom function. The custom function requires two columns of `df`.  I am not sure how to get it working.

I tried

```
df['newc'] = df['cond'].rolling(4).apply(T_correction, 
args = (df['temp'].rolling(4)))
```

This is obviously not working and this gives the following error:

```
raise NotImplementedError('See issue #11704 {url}'.format(url=url))
NotImplementedError: See issue #11704 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704
```

May be rolling.apply is not appropriate here. Looking for suggestions on alternate solutions.

```
>>> df.head()
                       temp   cond
ts
2018-06-01 00:00:00  51.908  27.83
2018-06-01 00:05:00  52.144  27.83
2018-06-01 00:10:00  51.880  27.83
2018-06-01 00:15:00  52.001  27.83
2018-06-01 00:20:00  51.835  27.83

def T_correction(df, d):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = df)
    df.columns = ['cond']
    df['temp'] = d
    X = df.drop(['cond'], axis = 1)    # X features: temp

    X = sm.add_constant(X)             # add intercept
    lmodel = sm.OLS(df.cond, X)        # fit cond = a + b*temp
    results = lmodel.fit()             #
    Op = results.predict(X)            # derive 'cond' as explained by temp
    Tc1 = df.cond - Op                 # remove the linear influence

#---conditional correction --------------------------------------
    Tc = np.where(df.temp > (np.mean(df.temp) + 0.5*np.std(df.temp)), df.cond, Tc1)
    return Tc[-1]     # returning the last value
```

The expected result:

```
>>> df.head()
                       temp   cond   newc
ts
2018-06-01 00:00:00  51.908  27.83   NaN
2018-06-01 00:05:00  52.144  27.83   NaN
2018-06-01 00:10:00  51.880  27.83   NaN
2018-06-01 00:15:00  52.001  27.83   26.00
2018-06-01 00:20:00  51.835  27.83   25.00
```

Comment: What do you want to modelise with `T_correction` ?

Comment: @Alexandre B applying some correction to `cond`, which is a function of `temp`

Comment: What is "*some corrections*"  ? Are you using `ols` ? why ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. I express `cond` as a linear function of `temp` through OLS. I then remove this (`cond = a + b* temp`) from `cond`.  This is `Tc1` in the function. `Tc` is where this `Tc1` is applied conditionally.

Comment: Do the solutions posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878917/how-to-invoke-pandas-rolling-apply-with-parameters-from-multiple-column help?

Comment: @hchw yes, did come across that post.  There were a few other similar posts but none addresses  similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this feature is currently not available.  There is an issue open on this topic on pandas github.  Please check: `https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15095`.