# Appending to next row the result of math operation between three columns

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have the following Pandas DataFrame where all values in third column (Ratio) are the same:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 10, 0.5], 
                   [float('NaN'), 10, 0.5], 
                   [float('NaN'), 5, 0.5]], columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Ratio'])
╔══════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Col1 ║ Col2 ║ Ratio ║
╠══════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 2    ║   10 ║ 0.5   ║
║ NaN  ║   10 ║ 0.5   ║
║ NaN  ║    5 ║ 0.5   ║
╚══════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

I want to know if there is a way to multiply Col1 * Ratio and then the output of that product add it to Col2 and append the value to next row Col1 using a function provided by pandas.

Output example:

```
╔══════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Col1 ║ Col2 ║ Ratio ║
╠══════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 2    ║   10 ║ 0.5   ║
║ 11   ║   10 ║ 0.5   ║
║ 15.5 ║    5 ║ 0.5   ║
╚══════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: better use for loop

Comment: @YOBEN_S that's what I want to avoid, if posible.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, as in your operation each row depends on the result of the previous row... so they must be executed in order.

(maybe you can avoid an explicit loop using `apply` or something, but that just loops under the hood...)

Comment: and ratio varies across the rows?

Comment: @QuangHoang Nope, ratio stay the same in all rows.

Comment: I think you're looking for window functions in pandas. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878917/how-to-invoke-pandas-rolling-apply-with-parameters-from-multiple-column) Stack Overflow question might point you in the right direction

Comment: @Adam.Er8 What you said is very similar to `ewm`, which is vectorizable. However, it might not worth implement such a solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [**numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba) is way how working with loops here if performance is important:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, b, c):
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        a[i] = a[i-1] * c[i-1] + b[i-1]
    return a

df['Col1'] = f(df['Col1'].to_numpy(), df['Col2'].to_numpy(), df['Ratio'].to_numpy())
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Ratio
0   2.0    10    0.5
1  11.0    10    0.5
2  15.5     5    0.5
```

Comment: So, how it seems there is not pandas built-in function to acchieve the goal of the question, I've marked this as the correct answer because at least it is focused on performance.