# .apply() a bivariate numpy() lambda function to an .expanding() window of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider this simple code (`numpy.sum` in `loc_fun` is a stand in for a more complicated bivariate function using numpy):

```
import pandas
import numpy


def loc_fun(A, B):
    return numpy.sum(A[:-1] > B[-1])


df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.normal(0, 1, [100000, 2]), columns=['size_A', 'size_B']).cumsum(axis=0)
df.expanding(2).apply(lambda x: loc_fun(x.size_A.values, x.size_B.values))
```

The last line in the code above results in an error I cannot make sense of.
Basically, I would like to apply `loc_fun` to an `expanding()` window of the values in the columns.

Comment: I think it is problem, because not yet implemented. `expanding` like `rolling` working with each column separately - check `print` + (`def f(x):
    print (x)
    return x.sum()

df = df.expanding(2).apply(f)`). So unfortunately need custom function without `expanding`. Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37486502), maybe help a bit.

Comment: Not sure, try contact author - `pir` is math really clever guy, I hope help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lambda x is a numpy.ndarray so You can not refer to column 'A-values' or 'B_values'.

```
df.expanding(2).apply(lambda x: print(type(x)))

>><class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Check my comment under question, unfortunately it working with each column separately :(

Comment: @Cezary.Sz: what version of pandas are you using? the line `df.expanding(2).apply(lambda x: print(type(x)))` itself gives an error here (p0.22)

Comment: Error is for second iteration, because  lambda get NoneType but in must be real number.

Comment: OK, in any case, jezrael's code in the comments does it. Darn: it will be more complicated than I thought.