# extracting an expanding window (numpy strided) of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

(related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41406783/189035))

Given a `df`, I was expecting to get the results of `df.expanding()` and to perform some multivariate operations on this (operations involving several columns of `df` simultaneously over an expanding window of rows) using `.apply()`. It turns out this is not possible.

So, much as in the answer linked above, I need to use `numpy.as_strides` of `df`. Except, in contrast to the question linked above, using strides to get an expanding views of my `df`, instead of rolling ones (an expanding window has a fixed left side and the right side moves to the right incrementally).

consider this `df`:

```
import numpy
import pandas


df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.normal(0, 1, [100, 2]), columns=['size_A', 'size_B']).cumsum(axis=0)
```

consider this code to extract a rolling window of `W` rows of that `df` (this comes from the answer above):

```
def get_sliding_window(df, W):
    a = df.values                 
    s0,s1 = a.strides
    m,n = a.shape
    return numpy.lib.stride_tricks\
               .as_strided(a,shape=(m-W+1,W,n),strides=(s0,s0,s1))

roll_window = get_sliding_window(df, W = 3)
roll_window[2]
```

Now I want to modify `get_sliding_window` to get it to return 
an expanding window of a df (instead of a rolling one):

```
def get_expanding_window(df):
    a = df.values                 
    s0,s1 = a.strides
    m,n = a.shape
    out = numpy.lib.stride_tricks\
               .as_strided(a, shape=(m,m,n),strides=(s0,s0,s1))
    return out

expg_window = get_expanding_window(df)
expg_window[2]
```

But I'm not using the arguments of  `as_strided` correctly: I can't seem to be getting the right matrices --that would be something like:

```
[df.iloc[0:1].values ,df.iloc[0:2].values, df.iloc[0:3].values,...]
```

## Edit:

In a comment @ThomasKühn proposes to use list comprehension. 
This would solve the problem, but too slowly. What is the cost?

One a vector valued function, we can compare the cost 
of list comprehension with `.expand()`. It ain't small:

```
numpy.random.seed(123)
df = pandas.DataFrame((numpy.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)), columns=['Value'])
%timeit method_1 = numpy.array([df.Value.iloc[range(j + 1)].sum() for j in range(df.shape[0])])
```

gives:

```
6.37 s ± 219 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

comparing to `.expanding()`:

```
%timeit method_2 = df.expanding(0).apply(lambda x: x.sum())
```

which gives:

```
35.5 ms ± 356 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Finally, there are more details as to the problem I am trying to solve 
in the comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48817828/189035) question.

Comment: Do you mean you want the left side of the window to be fixed and the right side to move to the right?

Comment: @ThomasKühn: yes (edited the question to make this more clear). Thanks!

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is not possible with `strides`, as they seem to assume fixed length. I think what you want are `slices`. To me this looks a bit like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/358966). Can you maybe elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: How about this: `indices = [i for j in range(1,5) for i in range(j)]` and then `df.iloc[indices]`. Is that what you want?

Comment: ...but do you need to *keep* these slices, or are you just doing some calculations on them? Just accessing a slice of an array (e.g. `a[3:5]`) only creates a [view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) of the array, so no data is copied. See also the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html): "All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array."

Comment: Forget about the 'indices=' comment, it's not going to be good for you. You want to go with slices. Something like `result = [your_function(a[0:i]) for i in range(1,max_i)]`. It's really hard to give a good example without a concrete idea of what you are up to.

Comment: If we forget about speed at first (and the DataFrame, which appears to be unnecessary for this problem), does this code calculate what you want? `x = np.random.normal(0,1,(10000,2)); res = [np.sum(x[:i,0] > x[i,1]) for i in range(x.shape[0])]`

Comment: @ThomasKühn: yes, speed is the only remaining issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a few functions that are all supposed to do the same thing, but need different amounts of time to complete the task:

```
import timeit
import numba as nb

x = np.random.normal(0,1,(10000,2))
def f1():
    res = [np.sum(x[:i,0] > x[i,1]) for i in range(x.shape[0])]
    return res

def f2():
    buf = np.empty(x.shape[0])
    res = np.empty(x.shape[0])
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        buf[:i] = x[:i,0] > x[i,1]
        res[i] = np.sum(buf[:i])
    return res

def f3():
    res = np.empty(x.shape[0])
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        res[i] = np.sum(x[:i,0] > x[i,1])
    return res


@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def f2_nb():
    buf = np.empty(x.shape[0])
    res = np.empty(x.shape[0])
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        buf[:i] = x[:i,0] > x[i,1]
        res[i] = np.sum(buf[:i])
    return res

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def f3_nb():
    res = np.empty(x.shape[0])
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        res[i] = np.sum(x[:i,0] > x[i,1])
    return res

##checking that all functions give the same result:
print('checking correctness')
print(np.all(f1()==f2()))
print(np.all(f1()==f3()))
print(np.all(f1()==f2_nb()))
print(np.all(f1()==f3_nb()))

print('+'*50)
print('performance tests')
print('f1()')        
print(min(timeit.Timer(
    'f1()',
    setup = 'from __main__ import f1,x',
).repeat(7,10)))

print('-'*50)
print('f2()')
print(min(timeit.Timer(
    'f2()',
    setup = 'from __main__ import f2,x',
).repeat(7,10)))

print('-'*50)
print('f3()')
print(min(timeit.Timer(
    'f3()',
    setup = 'from __main__ import f3,x',
).repeat(7,10)))

print('-'*50)
print('f2_nb()')
print(min(timeit.Timer(
    'f2_nb()',
    setup = 'from __main__ import f2_nb,x',
).repeat(7,10)))

print('-'*50)
print('f3_nb()')
print(min(timeit.Timer(
    'f3_nb()',
    setup = 'from __main__ import f3_nb,x',
).repeat(7,10)))
```

As you can see, the differences are not big, but there *are* some differences in performance. The last two functions are just 'duplicates' of earlier ones, but using `numba` optimisation. The results of the speed tests are

```
checking correctness
True
True
True
True
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
performance tests
f1()
2.02294262702344
--------------------------------------------------
f2()
3.0964318679762073
--------------------------------------------------
f3()
1.9573561699944548
--------------------------------------------------
f2_nb()
1.3796060049789958
--------------------------------------------------
f3_nb()
0.48667875200044364
```

As you can see, the differences are not terribly big, but between the slowest and the fastest function, the speedup is anyway about 6 times. Hope this helps.