# Smoothing a series of weighted values in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have a pandas DataFrame of measurements and corresponding weights:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randn(1000), 'w': np.random.rand(1000)})
```

I want to smooth the measurement values (`x`) while taking the element-wise
weights (`w`) into account. This is independent of the sliding window's weights,
which I'd also like to apply (e.g. a triangle window, or something fancier). So, to calculate the smoothed value within each window, the function should weight the sliced elements of `x` not only by the window function (e.g. triangle), but also by the corresponding elements in `w`.

As far as I can tell, `pd.rolling_apply` won't do it, because it applies the
given function over `x` and `w` separately. Similarly, `pd.rolling_window` also doesn't take the source DataFrame's element-wise weights into account; the weighted window (e.g.  'triangle') can be user-defined, but is fixed up front.

Here's my slow-ish implementation:

```
def rolling_weighted_triangle(x, w, window_size):
    """Smooth with triangle window, also using per-element weights."""
    # Simplify slicing
    wing = window_size // 2

    # Pad both arrays with mirror-image values at edges
    xp = np.r_[x[wing-1::-1], x, x[:-wing-1:-1]]
    wp = np.r_[w[wing-1::-1], w, w[:-wing-1:-1]]

    # Generate a (triangular) window of weights to slide
    incr = 1. / (wing + 1)
    ramp = np.arange(incr, 1, incr)
    triangle = np.r_[ramp, 1.0, ramp[::-1]]

    # Apply both sets of weights over each window
    slices = (slice(i - wing, i + wing + 1) for i in xrange(wing, len(x) + wing))
    out = (np.average(xp[slc], weights=triangle * wp[slc]) for slc in slices)
    return np.fromiter(out, x.dtype)
```

How can I speed this up with numpy/scipy/pandas?

The dataframe can take up a nontrivial portion of RAM already (10k to 200M rows), so e.g. allocating a 2D array of window-weights-per-element up front is too much. I'm trying to minimize the use of temporary arrays, maybe using
`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` and `np.apply_along_axis` or `np.convolve`, but haven't found anything to fully replicate the above.

Here's the equivalent with a uniform window, rather than a triangle (using the [get_sliding_window trick from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447347/dataframe-representation-of-a-rolling-window/41406783#41406783)) -- close but not quite there:

```
def get_sliding_window(a, width):
    """Sliding window over a 2D array.

    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447347/dataframe-representation-of-a-rolling-window/41406783#41406783
    """
    # NB: a = df.values or np.vstack([x, y]).T
    s0, s1 = a.strides
    m, n = a.shape
    return as_strided(a,
                     shape=(m-width+1, width, n),
                     strides=(s0, s0, s1))


def rolling_weighted_average(x, w, window_size):
    """Rolling weighted average with a uniform 'boxcar' window."""
    wing = window_size // 2
    window_size = 2 * wing + 1
    xp = np.r_[x[wing-1::-1], x, x[:-wing-1:-1]]
    wp = np.r_[w[wing-1::-1], w, w[:-wing-1:-1]]
    x_w = np.vstack([xp, wp]).T
    wins = get_sliding_window(x_w, window_size)
    # TODO - apply triangle window weights - multiply over wins[,:,1]?
    result = np.average(wins[:,:,0], axis=1, weights=wins[:,:,1])
    return result
```

Comment: Is this not equivalent to applying the window on `w*x`? Perhaps you can generate that column first?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be. The mean within a given window slice is not necessarily 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use convolution there, like so -

```
def rolling_weighted_triangle_conv(x, w, window_size):
    """Smooth with triangle window, also using per-element weights."""
    # Simplify slicing
    wing = window_size // 2

    # Pad both arrays with mirror-image values at edges
    xp = np.concatenate(( x[wing-1::-1], x, x[:-wing-1:-1] ))
    wp = np.concatenate(( w[wing-1::-1], w, w[:-wing-1:-1] ))

    # Generate a (triangular) window of weights to slide
    incr = 1. / (wing + 1)
    ramp = np.arange(incr, 1, incr)
    triangle = np.r_[ramp, 1.0, ramp[::-1]]

    D = np.convolve(wp*xp, triangle)[window_size-1:-window_size+1]
    N = np.convolve(wp, triangle)[window_size-1:-window_size+1]    
    return D/N
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [265]: x = np.random.randn(1000)
     ...: w = np.random.rand(1000)
     ...: WSZ = 7
     ...: 

In [266]: out1 = rolling_weighted_triangle(x, w, window_size=WSZ)
     ...: out2 = rolling_weighted_triangle_conv(x, w, window_size=WSZ)
     ...: print(np.allclose(out1, out2))
     ...: 
True

In [267]: %timeit rolling_weighted_triangle(x, w, window_size=WSZ)
     ...: %timeit rolling_weighted_triangle_conv(x, w, window_size=WSZ)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.9 µs per loop
```

**`300x+`** speedup there!

Comment: Fantastic. This approach also makes it easy to plug in another window shape like Kaiser in place of the triangle.

Comment: @EricTalevich Yup! Any kind of weight func is pluggable there.